# UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight not recognized by Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, uiviewanimationtransition

I am implementing a very simple flip animation, but the flip isn't there.

I am using an example from the docs as a template, Apple now recommends you use blocks for animations and that this is the approach to take: (from the docs)

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
           duration:0.2
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
           animations:^{ [fromView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:toView]; }
           completion:NULL];
```

Wrapping the two views you want to transition between in a container.
I do it like this.

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:target];
[self.view addSubview:container];
[container addSubview:productImage];

UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:target];
[background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[background setAlpha:0.1f];

[UIView transitionWithView:container
                  duration:0.8
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{ 
                    [[[container subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
                    [container addSubview:background]; 
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

Two strange things happen:
There is no transition, the container displays the productImage (of type UIImageView), then swaps it with the background view. No animation.

The second thing is what led me to believe that this is not the usual typo, was that the

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
```

is not recognized by Xcode, it will not autocomplete, it is not highlighted. Xcode will only do that if I use the deprecated:

```
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight //i.e. without the Option part
```

I then started to check my SDK version etc. everything seems to be set to 4.2, XCode is version 3.2.5, both target and project settings has build and deploy target set to 4.2.

What am I missing here?

Hope a set of trained eyes can help me:) thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going with blocks (and everyone should start going with them), please refer to
[+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a)

and/or

[+ (void)transitionWithView:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a)

Answer (score -1):

This code will help you

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];


UIViewAnimationTransition transition = UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight;
[UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:[self.navigationController view] cache:NO];


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Cheers

Comment: I presume you are using this animation at application launch,put this code in a method and call this method at launch time by invoking something like this...[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(initTab) userInfo:self repeats:NO]; where inittab would be the method containing the animation block of code..

Comment: Why would you presume that? I think Ricki wants to use the new blocks API. This is the old way to do animations. Apple's documentation says beginAnimations:context: should be avoided in new iOS 4 applications. However, I don't have a solution. I'm having the same problem myself.